# Spark - aggregated column disappears from a DataFrame after join

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I wanted to count the number of items for each `sale_id`and decided to use a count function. The idea was to have `item_numbers` as the last column and not to affect the original columns ordering from `salesDf`.

But after the join `sale_id` column became the first one in `df3`. So in order to fix this I tried `.select(salesDf.schema.fieldNames.map(col):_*)` However after that `item_numbers` column is missing (while other columns ordering is correct).

How do I preserve the correct ordering leaving `item_numbers` column in place at the same time?

```
 val df2 = salesDf.groupBy("sale_id").agg(count("item_id").as("item_numbers"))
 val df3 = salesDf.join(df2, "sale_id").select(salesDf.schema.fieldNames.map(col):_*)
```

Comment: May be not part of the original schema item_numbers?

Comment: @thebluephantom You are right. This is a new field that I want to append after performing an aggregation.

Comment: glad to have helped

Comment: @thebluephantom unfortunately I still don't understand how to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preserve `salesDf`'s column order in the final result, you could assemble the column list for `select` as follows:

```
val df2 = salesDf.groupBy("sale_id").agg(count("item_id").as("item_numbers"))
val df3 = salesDf.join(df2, "sale_id")

val orderedCols = salesDf.columns :+ "item_numbers"
val resultDF = df3.select(orderedCols.map(col): _*)
```